# VH change in MacOS in fullscreen browser

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive, viewport-units

The website I'm creating use a series of  which have min-height set at 100vh; inside of which a complex flexbox is used.

When finishing my website I notice something that annoys me :
when using Chrome on MacOS, when you are in fullscreen and you put your mouse at top, the macOS menu and window option show up causing the vh to change (not the case on Safari).

Problem is that it is recalculating every flexbox and change image zoom (as you can see in the picture). [with menu popped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOs4L.png) [without menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3c1O.png)

What would be a solution ? I still wish to make section based on vh as it renders good.enter image description here

Comment: _“I still wish to make section based on vh”_ - if that unit does not behave like you want it to in the first place, then you probably can’t really base a “solution” on it here either. You might need to look into measuring the screen/viewport height via JS, and then explicitly setting a (min-)height in pixels, or something.

Comment: It would have been more precise to say : "I still wish to make my section takes 100% of the height". So another way of asking would be : is there any trick with css (min-height, etc.. ) that would allow me to bypass, mitigate the effect of this vh change.

Comment: Not really … A min-height would also have to be based on _something_, and if you don’t want to use `vh` there, then - what?